# How to remove the disabled option from on option?

Tags: jquery

I practice to remove disabled attribute from an option on the link, https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_option_disabled.

I add few code to accomplish it as below,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<select>
  <option value="volvo" disabled>Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js">
    $("select[value='volvo']").removeAttr('disabled');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

or replace the script part with the one listed below,

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js">
    $("select[value='volvo']").attr('disabled', false);
</script>
```

But all of them are failed.
Did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current selector in your code does not match any element in the html as there is no `select` element with attribute `value` with value `volvo`. Hence, you need to update the selector to following where you select the option with said attribute/value combination.

**Note**: Alternatively, you could also use [jQuery.removeAttr()](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) like `$("select option[value='volvo']").removeAttr('disabled');`

```js
$("select option[value='volvo']").attr('disabled', false);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="volvo" disabled>Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: it works. Thank you. But I found if I add `volvo = 'volvo'
 $("select option[value=volvo]").attr('disabled', false);` in the https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_option_disabled and in your code snippet respectively, there will be different results. Do you know why?

Comment: Can you please explain the difference?

Comment: In your code snippet, the disabled attribute can be removed. But in  [link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_option_disabled), it can't.

Comment: In the link there must be some error coming as I cant see jQuery included in the snippet

Comment: Even though, `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
volvo = 'volvo';
$("select option[value=volvo]").attr('disabled', false);
</script>` is added, it still has no change.

Comment: If the script has src tag then body will be ignored. Try putting your script inside another script tag

Comment: @ Nikhil bingo. Yo are amazing. Thanks,